# How to do logging with firebase and google cloud?

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-platform

I'm using simply `console.log('some flag', someObject)` on Google Cloud and `functions.logger.log('some flag', someObject)` on firebase functions.

The problem is that both Firebase's admin panel logs page and Google Cloud's logs page makes this hard to read. Logs are getting split into lines. If my log had line breaks, then each line will be displayed as a separate log. Moreover, Google Clodu clearly has some kind of racing conditions when it comes to recording logs, as my logs are often displayed in the wrong order.

An obvious solution would be `console.log('some flag', JSON.stringify(someObject))`, but this makes logs hard to read in a different way. Now I have to copy the stringified object and `JSON.parse` it somewhere in browser console to make it readable.

What is the right way of writing logs in Firebase and Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Functions logger SDK provides a standard interface that has a similar api to **console.log** statements and supports other log levels. You can use this SDK to log events with structured data, enabling easier analysis and monitoring.

The logger SDK supports log entries as part of a wildcard import. For example:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's an object:", someObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

For Firebase Cloud Functions is better to use **functions:logger** to write logs and for reading logs use the command
**firebase functions:log** from CLI